# PHP Parse error with '>'

Tags: php

I'm just starting out with PHP, working on a small project. I'm trying to get a count and then show that count. Simple, right? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php
        $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","*****") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");

        mysql_select_db("department",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");

        $query = "select line, count(*) from students group by line";

        $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);

        echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" width=\"100%\"  style=\"border-collapse:collapse\"; cellpadding=\"2\">

        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
        {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "   <td align=\"center\">".$result[1]."</td>";
  echo "   <td align=\"center\">".$result[2]."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
        } echo "</table>";
?>

</html>
```

It's giving me the following error: `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>'` on the line that reads "`echo "<tr>";`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I lifted most of this code from another file that works just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: syntax highlighting is your friend :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: Others have pointed out your syntax error, so I won't bother doing so again. Quite often when programming an error will have a knock on effect to other lines. Be careful to check all lines around the affected area, as well as the line the error specifies.

Comment: @PeeHaa The question is in fact about an error. That the error is caused by a typo doesn't negate that fact.

Comment: @chumkiu, I'm using Sublime Text but it doesn't show syntax highlighting. Is there something else I should be using?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas SublimeText is php compatible. try to find in web more info about php support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic line is here, you forgot to close a string :

```
echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" width=\"100%\"  style=\"border-collapse:collapse\"; cellpadding=\"2\">
```

Change it to

```
echo "<table align=\"left\" border=\"1\" width=\"100%\"  style=\"border-collapse:collapse\"; cellpadding=\"2\">";
```

You can notice it by looking at your code color : syntax highlighting shows you that `while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))` is considered as a string here (it's red).